# Add 'jump to' functionality to material pagination in angular

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

I need to add a 'jump to' functionality to material pagination. it doesn't have built-in method for that so I need to add it manually.

at the moment I have this code:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="pageLength"
                       [pageSize]="10"
                       [pageSizeOptions]="pageLength | checkPageLength"
                       [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
        </mat-paginator>
```

and it shows:
[image: my current pagination]

and I need it to have a textbox and a 'go' button for jumping to a specific page since I have many pages.

Comment: Hii Amri , did you solve this problem at all?

Comment: Hi @Kaczkapojebana unfortunately not yet

Comment: hii Amir I solve the problem I will share the answer

Answer (score -2):

```
  table-pagination-example.html

             <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
                      <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

                        <!-- Position Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
                          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
                          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
                     </ng-container>

                        <!-- Name Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
                          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- Weight Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
                          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
                          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- Symbol Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
                          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
                          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                      </mat-table>
                      <span class="paginator-wrapper mat-paginator-container">
                      <span class="page-index-selector mat-paginator-page-size">
                        <span class="page-index-text-wrapper mat-select-trigger mat-paginator-page-size-label">
                          Page index:
                        </span>

                        <mat-form-field class="mat-paginator-page-size-select mat-primary">
                           <input #pageSelect matInput type="number" [max]="pages"  [min]="1"  [ngModel]="getPage" (change)="pageToIndex($event.target.value)">
                        </mat-form-field>
                      </span>

                      <mat-paginator #paginator
                                     [pageSize]="10"
                                     [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                                     [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
                      </mat-paginator>
                       </span>
                    </div>

        table-pagination-example.ts

            import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
            import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

            @Component({
              selector: 'table-pagination-example',
              styleUrls: ['table-pagination-example.css'],
              templateUrl: 'table-pagination-example.html',
            })
            export class TablePaginationExample {
              displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
              dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);

              @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

              ngAfterViewInit() {
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
              }

            get pages() {
                return this.paginator.getNumberOfPages();
              }

              get getPage() {
                return this.paginator.pageIndex + 1;
              }

              pageToIndex(pageIndex) {
                if (pageIndex < 0) {
                  pageIndex = pageIndex * -1;
                }
                this.paginator.pageIndex = pageIndex - 1;
                }
            }

            export interface Element {
              name: string;
              position: number;
              weight: number;
              symbol: string;
            }

            const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
              {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
              {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
              {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
              {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
              {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
              {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
              {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
              {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
              {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
              {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
              {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
              {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
              {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
              {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
              {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
              {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
              {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
              {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
              {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
              {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
              {position: 21, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
              {position: 22, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
              {position: 23, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
              {position: 24, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
              {position: 25, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
              {position: 26, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
              {position: 27, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
              {position: 28, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
              {position: 29, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
              {position: 30, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
              {position: 31, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
              {position: 32, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
              {position: 33, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
              {position: 34, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
              {position: 35, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
              {position: 36, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
              {position: 37, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
              {position: 38, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
              {position: 39, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
              {position: 40, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'}
            ];
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it